# ROFI Temperature

Tags: space-shuttle, engines, launchpad, sls, hydrogen

Since hydrogen-fueled rockets usually require Radial Outward Firing Igniters (ROFI), what is the temperature of the sparks from this system? When seen at RS-25/RS-68 ignition, they don't melt but seemingly flow down with the rocket exhaust into the flame trench.[image: ROFI Ignition as seen during STS-135]

Answer (score 1):

Radially Outward Firing Igniters (ROFI) are a subtype of Hydrogen Burn Off Igniter (HBOI). PACSCI EMC, a manufacturer of HBOI, specifies their HBOI output sparks “at least” 1,500*F.
[https://psemc.com/products/hydrogen-burn-off-igniters/#:~:text=Another%20common%20version%20of%20this,accumulation%20of%20hydrogen%20during%20launch](https://psemc.com/products/hydrogen-burn-off-igniters/#:%7E:text=Another%20common%20version%20of%20this,accumulation%20of%20hydrogen%20during%20launch)

The ignition temperature of hydrogen in air is about 1100*F [https://seshydrogen.com/en/safety-of-hydrogen-systems/#:~:text=The%20standard%20auto%2Dignition%20temperature,compared%20to%20long%20molecule%20hydrocarbons](https://seshydrogen.com/en/safety-of-hydrogen-systems/#:%7E:text=The%20standard%20auto%2Dignition%20temperature,compared%20to%20long%20molecule%20hydrocarbons)

However. The fact that sparks are visible as yellow light implies a black body temperature of over 3000*F

My understanding is that ROFI, an early design of igniter, used a small solid fuel rocket motor with an annular discharge ring replacing the nozzle. Hence the “radially outward firing”. The design quoted above has a linear discharge with a specified “throw” distance. Although it is not “radially outward firing”, they are still informally referred to as "ROFI"s since "HBOI" is harder to say.

I don’t have a solid reference for this, just Tweets by Tony Bruno (CEO United Launch Allaince) and Scott Manley https://twitter.com/torybruno/status/1311552569530081280?lang=en

[image: https://www.mdpi.com/2076-3417/12/7/3414]

Comment: I'm not sure "H-boy" is actually harder to say than "rofi", but still, habits are hard to break.